# Atomically clone struct

Tags: c#, struct, concurrency, atomic

Let's say I have a struct, no matter how is defined, but let's assume it's mutable. For example:

```
struct Point
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}
```

Also, let's assume there's a class exposing a property which returns a value of that type `Point` (struct).

```
class C
{
    private Point _pos;  //mutable
    public Point Position { get { return _pos; } }
}
```

Of course, when I get the value from Position, I actually get a copy of the original value.

```
Point pos = c.Position;
```

However, I have no guarantee about atomicity in a concurrent context, and I may get a corrupted value.

The question is: is there any ready-to-use mechanism (kind of `Interlock.whatever`) which allows to clone a struct safely in a concurrent context?

Comment: You can only do this by controlling read and write access to the item that you want to clone - otherwise it'll be impossible to prevent one thread from updating the struct while another is reading it.

Comment: Note that you don't need the struct in the sample, copying a `double` is already non-atomic. Bite the bullet and `lock(){ }`.

Comment: I agree, but how do they solve the problem for Int64 in a 32-bit environment? Isn't that the same problem? For instance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs86dyzy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just don't make this struct mutable? This is a bad practice for a reason.

Comment: @Evk as correctly Henk Holtermann pointed out, even a double as well as many others framework types have the same problem. If you don't like the struct, just think to a simple double: is there any ready-to-use function which clones a double without worrying?

Comment: I see what you mean. No, I don't think so, so you have to make your struct immutable and then lock in getter\setter of your `Point` to guarantee it is in consistent state. With single double I think you can use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` for read and `Interlocked.Exchange` for write.

Comment: The `long CompareExchange(ref long location1, ...)` is only needed in 32 bit mode. `double CompareExchange(ref double location1, ...)` solves the problem for the remaining built-in _primitive_ types. After that you're on your own. Note that DateTime isn't supported by Interlocked either, they had to draw a line I think.